# Problems in trying to POST json data to python flask server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I am trying to Post a json to my flask server, but the post request always fails. This is how I am doing it, any idea what is am doing wrong?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/someLink',
    method:'POST',
    data:JSON.stringify({"sampleKey":"Value"}),
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

And my flask server looks something like

```
@app.route('/someLink', methods=['POST'])
def someFn():
 sampleKey = str(request.form['sampleKey'])
```

I believe there is some data serializing issue, as the following request works

```
jQuery.post('/someLink',{"sampleKey":"Value"},function(data){console.log(data)});
```

Comment: Any progress? Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Hey Benjamin, I am stuck with my class homework, havent got time to look at it yet. Shall let you know in a few hours. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.ajax` accepts either a plain object, or a query string as parameters for data. It does not accept JSON encoded strings.

It sends the data as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` by default, which means unless you explicitly override this like Ian suggested possible (and the server is expecting it) you should not pass a JSON encoded string.

You can resolve this easily by passing the object.

From [the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **data**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Try

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/someLink',
    method:'POST',
    data:{"sampleKey":"Value"},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It does accept JSON encoded strings - you can set the `contentType` option as "application/json". But I think the server has to know how to understand/parse it. Nonetheless, your answer seems right, because you're passing the same object data as the OP's `$.post()`

Comment: @Ian this is new to me (JSON strings as `data:`) and seems contradictory to what the API docs say, would you mind whipping up a fiddle showing this (jsfiddle does JSON at /echo/json)?

Comment: @Ian Nevermind. I got what you mean, just sending a string as the BODY of the POST request and telling the server the form is encoded using `application/json` instead of url-encoded. It's not a specific feature. Good point, I'll update the answer, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's only when the `contentType` is overridden. So it's not a `$.ajax()` feature technically. I probably shouldn't have mentioned it, but it caught my eye, because I know I've seen people use it before (not me personally). I wasn't trying to say it should be used here or yours is wrong; just commenting on that one sentence you have

Comment: Hey guys, unfortunately the soln didnt work. So I created a switch catch and used jQuery.get and jQuery.post both.

Comment: @anonymous123 That is a _bad_ solution, you're sending _two requests_ to the server, what didn't work about it?

Comment: I am not sending 2 requests. I just have an if case to decide whether its a post request or a get request, and send the corresponding one. Its not the most elegant of solutions but it works properly.